# How to login into Google by webscraping in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-signin

I have been trying to enter google web page by webscraping the page using python (selium and beutifulsoup)  however it requires login the problem is that I make a post request to enter my e-mail but it doesn´t change page:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post(new_url, data={
            "email": 'my_mail_here',
        })
        new_url = driver.current_url
        driver.get(new_url)
        time.sleep(3)
        p = s.post(new_url, data={
            "password": "my_pass_here"
        })
        new_url = driver.current_url
        driver.get(new_url)
        time.sleep(3)
        base_page = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(base_page.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium you can use send_keys. Install selenium, install browser driver, give selenium the locations of browser and your driver. Navigate to the website. Inspect the input boxes for username and password. Find the element using xpath, class, id whatever fits your needs. Use send keys as below. This is a rough setup for Mac. Windows is slightly different.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from random import randint as rnd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/Users/user/Desktop/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
chrome_driver_exec = '/Users/user/Documents/WebDrivers/chromedriver-3'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_exec, options=options)

driver.get('https://website.com')
driver.set_window_size(1440, 900)
time.sleep(rnd(3, 5))
# login
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(rnd(3, 5))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/input').send_keys('username')
time.sleep(rnd(2, 4))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys('password')
```